# MySQL concatenate to column while selecting

Tags: mysql

I'm dealing with a bit of a legacy database here, and I'm having some trouble with writing a search query.

The two tables concerned are `products` and `tours` (multiple per product).

My general query looks like this:

```
SELECT products.*, tours.* FROM products INNER JOIN tours 
ON products.id=tours.product_id
GROUP BY products.id
```

Now here's the part where I'm having trouble. The `products` table contains a column, `countries`, which is a pipe-seperated list of country id's, like so: `13|45|33|29|133|337`. I need to return a list of `products` that have, for example, country `33`.

For simplicity, I could do `where products.countries LIKE '%33%'`, but this would return `133` and `337` as well. I'll need to use `where products.countries LIKE '%|33|%'`, but this won't match them if they're first or last. Therefore, I need to append a pipe to either end of the column value when selecting, which leaves me with something like:

```
SELECT products.*, tours.*, CONCAT("|",products.countries,"|") AS country_list
FROM products INNER JOIN tours ON products.id=tours.product_id
GROUP BY products.id
```

But if I attempt to add `WHERE country_list LIKE '|%33%|'`, I get an `"undefined index: country_list"` error..

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try WHERE products.countries LIKE '%33%',

Comment: @helle that would also match `133` and `337`, which is incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases are not availible in WHERE clauses. Just in HAVING clauses

"An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses to refer to the column" [1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-with-alias.html)

So you can either do

```
HAVING country_list LIKE '|%33%|'
```

Or the satement without Aliases, that Scott posted.

Comment: Thanks. I Used Scott's solution, but I'm accepting this one because I think it answers the question best.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
WHERE CONCAT("|",products.countries,"|") LIKE '%|33|%'
```

note that the pipes are within the percent signs

Comment: Just so I understand, you can't reference the alias in the WHERE clause, can you?

Comment: Great, that works. Any explanation for the error, and why I can't select it?